# compare 2 dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It is the first time I use pandas and I do not really know how to deal with my problematic.

In fact I have 2 data frame:

```
import pandas 

blast=pandas.read_table("blast")
cluster=pandas.read_table("cluster")
```

Here is an exemple of their contents:

```
 >>> cluster
       cluster_name            seq_names
0                 1           g1.t1_0035
1                 1      g1.t1_0035_0042
2            119365           g1.t1_0042
3             90273      g1.t1_0042_0035
4             71567          g10.t1_0035
5             37976     g10.t1_0035_0042
6             22560          g10.t1_0042
7             90280     g10.t1_0042_0035
8             82698         g100.t1_0035
9             47392    g100.t1_0035_0042
10            28484         g100.t1_0042
11            22580    g100.t1_0042_0035
12            19474        g1000.t1_0035
13             5770   g1000.t1_0035_0042
14            29708        g1000.t1_0042
15            99776   g1000.t1_0042_0035
16             6283       g10000.t1_0035
17            39828  g10000.t1_0035_0042
18            25383       g10000.t1_0042
19           106614  g10000.t1_0042_0035
20             6285       g10001.t1_0035
21            13866  g10001.t1_0035_0042
22           121157       g10001.t1_0042
23           106615  g10001.t1_0042_0035
24             6286       g10002.t1_0035
25              113  g10002.t1_0035_0042
26            25397       g10002.t1_0042
27           106616  g10002.t1_0042_0035
28             4643       g10003.t1_0035
29            13868  g10003.t1_0035_0042
...             ...                  ...
```

and

```
    [78793 rows x 2 columns]
    >>> blast
                      qseqid               sseqid  pident  length  mismatch  \
0            g1.t1_0035_0042      g1.t1_0035_0042   100.0     286         0   
1            g1.t1_0035_0042           g1.t1_0035   100.0     257         0   
2            g1.t1_0035_0042        g9307.t1_0035    26.9     134        65   
3            g2.t1_0035_0042      g2.t1_0035_0042   100.0     445         0   
4            g2.t1_0035_0042           g2.t1_0035    95.8     451         3   
5            g2.t1_0035_0042  g24520.t1_0042_0035    61.1     429       137   
6            g2.t1_0035_0042        g9924.t1_0042    61.1     429       137   
7            g2.t1_0035_0042        g1838.t1_0035    86.2      29         4   
8            g3.t1_0035_0042      g3.t1_0035_0042   100.0     719         0   
9            g3.t1_0035_0042           g3.t1_0035    84.7     753        62   
10           g4.t1_0035_0042      g4.t1_0035_0042   100.0     242         0   
11           g4.t1_0035_0042           g3.t1_0035    98.8     161         2   
12           g5.t1_0035_0042      g5.t1_0035_0042   100.0     291         0   
13           g5.t1_0035_0042           g3.t1_0035    93.1     291         0   
14           g6.t1_0035_0042      g6.t1_0035_0042   100.0     152         0   
15           g6.t1_0035_0042           g4.t1_0035   100.0     152         0   
16           g7.t1_0035_0042      g7.t1_0035_0042   100.0     216         0   
17           g7.t1_0035_0042           g5.t1_0035    98.1     160         3   
18           g7.t1_0035_0042       g11143.t1_0042    46.5     230        99   
19           g7.t1_0035_0042  g27537.t1_0042_0035    40.8     233       111   
20        g3778.t1_0035_0042   g3778.t1_0035_0042   100.0      86         0   
21        g3778.t1_0035_0042        g6174.t1_0035    98.0      51         1   
22        g3778.t1_0035_0042  g20037.t1_0035_0042   100.0      50         0   
23        g3778.t1_0035_0042       g37190.t1_0035   100.0      50         0   
24        g3778.t1_0035_0042  g15112.t1_0042_0035    66.0      53        18   
25        g3778.t1_0035_0042        g6061.t1_0042    66.0      53        18   
26       g18109.t1_0035_0042  g18109.t1_0035_0042   100.0      86         0   
27       g18109.t1_0035_0042       g33071.t1_0035   100.0      81         0   
28       g18109.t1_0035_0042       g32810.t1_0035    96.4      83         3   
29       g18109.t1_0035_0042  g17982.t1_0035_0042    98.6      72         1   
...                      ...                  ...     ...     ...       ...
```

if you stay focus on the cluster database, the first column correspond to the cluster ID and inside those clusters there are several sequences ID. 
What I need to to is first to split all my cluster (in R it would be like: `liste=split(x = data$V2, f = data$V1)` )

And then, creat a function which displays the most similarity paires sequence within each cluster.
here is an exemple:

let's say I have two clusters (dataframe cluster):

```
cluster 1: 
seq1
seq2
seq3
seq4
cluster 2:
seq5
seq6
seq7
```

...

On the blast dataframe there is on the 3th column the similarity between all sequences (all against all), so something like:

```
seq1 vs seq1 100
seq1 vs seq2 90
seq1 vs seq3 56
seq1 vs seq4 49
seq1 vs seq5 40
....
seq2 vs seq3 70
seq2 vs seq4 98
...
seq5 vs seq5 100
seq5 vs seq6 89
seq5 vs seq7 60
seq7 vs seq7 46
seq7 vs seq7 100
seq6 vs seq6 100
```

and what I need to get is :

```
cluster 1 (best paired sequences): 
seq 1 vs seq 2

cluster2 (best paired sequences):
seq 5 vs seq6
```

...

So as you can see, I do not want to take into account the sequences paired by themselves

IF someone could give me some clues it would be fantastic.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I assume that there are no Pairings in 'blast' with sequences from two different Clusters. In other words: in this solution the cluster-ID of a pairing will be evaluated by only one of the two sequence IDs.

Including cluster information and pairing information into one dataframe:

```
data = cluster.merge(blast, left_on='seq_names', right_on='qseqid')
```

Then the data should only contain pairings of different sequences:

```
data = data[data['qseqid']!=data['sseqid']]
```

To ignore pairings which have the same substrings in their seqid, the most readable way would be to add data columns with these data:

```
data['qspec'] = [seqid.split('_')[1] for seqid in data['qseqid'].values]
data['sspec'] = [seqid.split('_')[1] for seqid in data['sseqid'].values]
```

Now equal spec-values can be filtered the same way like it was done with equal seqids above:

```
data = data[data['qspec']!=data['sspec']]
```

In the end the data should be grouped by cluster-ID and within each group, the maximum of pident is of interest:

```
data_grpd = data.groupby('cluster_name')
result = data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].idxmax()]
```

The only drawback here - except the above mentioned assumption - is, that if there are several exactly equal max-values, only one of them would be taken into account.

Note: if you don't want the spec-columns to be of type string, you could easiliy turn them into integers on the fly by:

```
import numpy as np
data['qspec'] = [np.int(seqid.split('_')[1]) for seqid in data['qseqid'].values]
```

Comment: I do not have access to my data from my home but I will try it tomorrow. If I well understood I should get for each cluster containing at least  sequences, the best paired sequences based on those who have the max pident right? And cluster who have only one sequence should not be display (logical because if theire is only one sequence on a cluster, the only pident possible is against itself) as well as sequences paires with themselves? Thanks for you help ! :) I hope it will works

Comment: Ok It works ahah. Now that we have removed all sequences paired with the same ID do you think it is possible to also remove resquence which begins with the same paterne after the first "_"? For exemple: if the 2 sequences compared are: g1.t1_0035_0042 vs g1.t1_0035 or g23602.t1_0035_0042 vs g44900.t1_0035 or g23622.t1_0035_0042 vs g7499.t1_0042. In fact the first number correspond at the specie number so when the two number are equal, it means that we are comparing the same specie. Do you think it is possible as we did when the seq id are equal to also removed those sequences with the same n°?

Comment: I edited the answer with respect to your question about filtering species-values.

Comment: Thanks for you help but something is going wrong (I created a new comment to explain it)

Comment: Sorry - I cannot reproduce your issue here. Even by copying the sample data you posted here, I have only the part, where it works so far...

Comment: OK I see, I put the files' links in my comment above, I hope it will works

Comment: Ho yes, sorry, it's fixed.

Comment: My fault: the max-method in `data.groupby().max()` returns all Maximum values, i.e. in each group you receive the Maximum value of every individual column - which of course doesn't preserve the row-structure. What you Need is a Maximum-calculation which is better described as a filter, so it has to be informed about which column should be checked for max, so that the row with this Maximum value only in this column can be returned. You find the according code in the middle of the post in the latest edit, it is `data_grpd = data.groupby('cluster_name')`
`data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].idxmax()]`

Comment: I left a new comment

Comment: Misunderstanding: `data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].idxmax()]` does not change `data`, it applies the filter to `data`, so that the Output is the required filtration (without touching data at all, to be clear). So do two lines with grouping and filtering at the very end. first throw away your self-to-self-Pairings and the Pairings with equal spec, and then afterwards do grouping and idxmax()-filtering. Print the result of `data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].idxmax()]` or put it in a new variable `result`.

Comment: Your usage of merge is ok: Either `data = cluster.merge(blast, left_on='seq_names', right_on='qseqid')` or `data = blast.merge(cluster, left_on='qseqid', right_on='seq_names')` Please try the correct order of the rest of the code as I described obove.

Comment: By the way: should your almost 100MB-package of data permanently be accessible to anybody in the whole world...?

Comment: Ok I will try, and what abour the part :  : `data = cluster.merge(blast, left_on='seq_names', right_on='qseqid') ` you used: `data = cluster.blast(cluster, left_on='seq_names', right_on='qseqid') `but if I write it this way I get the error message: `KeyError: 'qseqid'`

Comment: No, please read carefully: if you swap cluster and blast in this line you also have to swap the strings of left_on and right_on. My first usage of this does not fit to your data, as I didn't have it at this time, so take the Version which does the Job. (And `cluster.blast` doesn't make sense at all, by the way...)

Comment: Hi again, after all, I realized that I had some clusters in my data which contained sometime two or more identical paired sequences. In other words: in one cluster I can have for exemple: sp1 vs sp 2 89, sp1 vs sp2 70 and sp3 vs sp4 50 and what I need to add at the scrip is to keep these two homologous paired sequences, not juste keep the first one which has the best pident score (in fact they are RHP I do not know if you know the what it means?). Do you think it is possible? Thanks you :)

Comment: to be honest - no. if i web-search 'rhp' in germany i get results which, ... however, off topic...     but seriuosly: the only question for me is: isn't that a contradiction to your initial target? you wanted to filter the best `pident` - now you want the best two, or more? Please clarify this.

Comment: OK, in fact these paired sequences should be homologous but in the same gene, there can be several homologous area called HSP (high-scoring pairs) not RHP sorry, it is something else. So yes indeed I need to get the best pident per cluster but if I have several HSP in the same cluster, then I have to keep all of theme because they come from the same paired gene. Is it better?

Comment: Let me add a comment whith the new data I got and with more explanation. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is this info about HSP or RHP or whatever available in your dataset?

Comment: I wrote a comment with more details, and it is all about Hsp, I made a mistake writting rhp sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This merges the dataframes based first on sseqid, then on qseqid, and then returns results_df. Any with 100% match are filtered out. Let me know if this works. You can then order by cluster name.

```
blast = blast.loc[blast['pident'] != 100]
results_df = cluster.merge(blast, left_on='seq_names',right_on='sseqid')
results_df = results_df.append(cluster.merge(blast, left_on='seq_names',right_on='qseqid'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)